# How to force ArgoCD to use _helpers.tpl in Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have created a Helm chart that involves a function from _helpers.tpl file

```
{{- define "awsLBTargetGroupArn" -}}
{{- (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "nginx-proxy" "proxy-cm").data.targetgroup_arn }}
{{- end -}}
```

That function is taking a value from a configmap and passes that value to a CRD TargetGroupBinding that doesn't understand the concept of ConfigMaps. So yes- it is a little hack against the limitations of the TargetGroupBinding CRD itself.

I am using the output of it in a way

```
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-tgb
  namespace: nginx-proxy
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: nginx-proxy-service
    port: 443
  targetGroupARN: {{ include "awsLBTargetGroupArn" . }}
```

The problem is, that when I am doing a helm install dry-run, I've got an error.

```
helm install nginx-proxy ./ --dry-run
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: nginx-proxy/templates/tgbinding.yaml:10:21: executing "nginx-proxy/templates/tgbinding.yaml" at <include "awsLBTargetGroupArn" .>: error calling include: template: nginx-proxy/templates/_helpers.tpl:2:43: executing "awsLBTargetGroupArn" at <"proxy-cm">: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.targetgroup_arn
```

I know after a research, that Helm is not running those functions in a dry-run mode, so it cannot pass the value down to the templates. It is working as it should when I just do a helm install without a dry-run. Ok then... it is what it is.
The problem for me now is, that ArgoCD is most probably doing same dry-run before deploying application, cause I am having same error while trying to deploy it using ArgoCD.

So the question is, how can I force ArgoCD to deploy it anyway, and will I have similar problems in future with other apps and charts that uses _helpers.tpl ?

Answer (score 0):

Argo CD executes `helm template` to generate manifests, then applies these manifests to the cluster. You can check this information in [Argo CD FAQ](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#after-deploying-my-helm-application-with-argo-cd-i-cannot-see-it-with-helm-ls-and-other-helm-commands):

> When deploying a Helm application Argo CD is using Helm only as a template mechanism. It runs helm template and then deploys the resulting manifests on the cluster instead of doing helm install

`helm template` not access cluster to make lookup request, as we can see in [helm lookup docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function).

> Keep in mind that Helm is not supposed to contact the Kubernetes API Server during a helm template or a helm install|upgrade|delete|rollback --dry-run, so the lookup function will return an empty list (i.e. dict) in such a case.

Actually, there is an open issue in the Argo CD repository: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/5202

Comment: There's also a proposal for an equivalent feature to be built into Argo CD instead of Helm. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/12050